# Alarme Android / IOS com PhoneGap

Tags: android, ios, apache-cordova, plugin

Boa noite, estou acabando de desenvolver uma aplicação para festas. Nessa aplicação lista as festas da cidade com data e horário, ingressos e tals.. Estou com uma dificuldade em criar uma funcionalidade, eu preciso notificar o usuário que a festa vai começar com a antecedência solicitada por ele.

Preciso do plugin para emitir um aviso sonoro e exibir uma mensagem de notificação para informar que o evento esta para ocorrer, esse plugin precisaria funcionar em android/ios com o Apache Cordova.

> O plugin deveria notificar mesmo que o aplicativo estivesse fechado, como se fosse um serviço do android.

Comment: Para fazer o serviço funcionar em background você pode utilizar o plugin https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um *plugin* que pode ser usado é o [Cordova Local-Notification](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications).

> O objetivo essencial de local-notifications é permitir que um aplicativo informe seus usuários que ele tem algo para eles - por
>   exemplo, uma mensagem ou um compromisso futuro - não quando o
>   aplicativo é executado em segundo plano. Eles são programados por um
>   aplicativo e entregue no mesmo dispositivo.

As [plataformas suportadas](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#supported-platforms) são:

- Android (*>= 7*)
- iOS
- Windows Phone *7/8*
- BlackBerry *10*

Engine: cordova (*>= 3.0.0*)

Alguns exemplos podem ser vistos [**aqui**](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#examples).

Comment: Obrigado QMechanic73.